# How would a secretive vestigial population grow alongside humans, given that they live different lifestyles?

Tags: warfare, humanoid, history, population

This is a heavily revised version of a post I made earlier, along with some edits from my friend Enthalpy.
This new post is strictly about population growth, and contains no extant references to third party content.

I've posted the original prompt here, but we've made some calculations of our own, and I'll attach them below.

Presumably, in 1800, DKs live to be up to 30 years old.
From Enthalpy:
"

- All alive human beings advance 20 years. Children become adults, adults become elderly, and elderly die.
- Each currently alive adults adds "average number of children per woman," with a 1.2 multiplier.
- The number of living children is adjusted by the child mortality rate (under five years ago), with a 1.4 multiplier.

At 1940, this gives you 69k children, 24k adults, 8k elderly for 100k total.
This is probably way too high. Assuming that anybody who lives until the age of five will live into old age is simply not realistic, but those were the numbers I were able to find fast."

https://www.statista.com/statistics/1033027/fertility-rate-us-1800-2020/
https://www.statista.com/statistics/1041693/united-states-all-time-child-mortality-rate/

In 1940, I currently believe that the population shifted, in a drastic way. However, I'm interested in charting the population as it would ought to look, given the numbers we have here.

I'm interested in seeing how you all might help me iron out these numbers a bit, as well as figuring out what the population should look like in the modern day. We have our baseline, for what that's worth, but I've love to hear what you all think.

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because brainstorming, idea generation, and soliciting opinions are not permitted on this site.

Comment: Is it allowed to discuss math like this? I can take this elsewhere in case there's somewhere more appropriate for this type of conversation.

Comment: We do answer questions that are predominantly math on this site. But you're not asking a math question, you're asking us to "Iron out your numbers", figure out what the population should look like, and share our thoughts. None of these are suitable questions for this site. You should also replace that image of text with actual text to assist with readability and accessibility.

Comment: If this is a revision of something you have already posted you should revise that post rather than, reposting and circumventing question closure.

Comment: To compute any kind of population growth you need demographic data, which the question does not give. What is the life expectancy at birth? Life expectancy at the age of ten? What is the average fertility? You say that "they are 20% likelier to have children". Likelier than what? And please, when you post text, post text, not a picture of the text.

Comment: How insular is the ethnic group?  If all DK intermarry with non-DK then there will be literally twice as many children each generation as there would be with 0% intermarriage.  That single unknown factor changes possible answers by three orders of magnitude from 1800 to 2020(ish).

Comment: You should edit your original post, not reposting it as new, because doing so circumvents our quality policies. Also avoid screenshots of text, because they make it harder for some users to read their content.

Comment: Thank you all for letting me know all of this, I will amend my previous post.